# Trying to activate a theme in Yii & installing Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, themes

I have managed to create the "Testdrive" application on my test yii install. I *think* I've installed Bootstrap.

More importantly I'm struggling to activate the theme I'd like to use. I have gone through all Yii tutorials I can find and have changed the `'theme' => 'xxxx'` without success.

I have double-checked file/folder permissions to eliminate obvious mistakes.

The url to see the demo site live is http://www.pureads.co.uk/testdrive

Feel free to ask me anything and I'll answer as best I can.

Here's my `protected/config/main.php` file in which I have *tried* to call in the theme I have sitting in `/testdrive/themes` but doesn't appear to be working.

```
    <?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.

return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'My Web Application',
    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),

    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
    ),
    'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'Enter Your Password Here',
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        ),

    ),

    // application components
    'components'=>array(
        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        ),
        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
        /*
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
        */
        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
        ),
        // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database
        /*
        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdrive',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
        */
        'errorHandler'=>array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),
        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
                /*
                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ),
                */
            ),
        ),
    ),

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
    ),
    'theme'=>'andia-agency', // requires you to copy the theme under your themes directory
    'modules'=>array(
        'gii'=>array(
            'generatorPaths'=>array(
                'bootstrap.gii',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'components'=>array(
        'bootstrap'=>array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: what are the contents of `themes/andia-agency` folder? and remeber fro installing bootstrap, you dont have to duplicate `components` property

Comment: There's a folder called Assets and five html files called about, contact, index, portfolio & services. In the Assets folders there are folders called bootstrap, css, font-awesome, ico, img, js & prettyPhoto plus one file called sendmail.php. Thanks.

Comment: I was running into headaches with themes recently and found debugging everything XDebug helped a lot

Answer (score 2):

Your *themes* folder should have the same structure as your *protected/views/* folder. So your theme should be setup as follows (relative to the root directory of course).

- themes

  - views
  - layouts
  - site

I sometimes have issues getting the 'theme' config option to work right. Usually I add the following inside of my controller in CController::beforeAction($action);

```
Yii::app()->setTheme('andia-agency');
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you include

```
    <?php Yii::app()->bootstrap->register(); ?>
```

into your `<head></head>` section ??

This worked for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

For Yii version 1.xx , please follow the following site & youtube for setup instructions:

> http://docs.siquo.net/yii-bootstrap/setup.html
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jw7hVR7EGHc

### 1) copy the theme directory to your themes directory

The instructions to copy the Theme (bootstrap) to Themes (yii) folder [which is the case but] is somehow lost in translation.

### 2) Yii project >> protected > config > main.php

```
// Define a path alias for the Bootstrap extension as it's used internally.
// In this example we assume that you unzipped the extension under protected/extensions.

Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap');

return array(
    'theme'=>'bootstrap', // requires you to copy the theme under your themes directory
    'modules'=>array(
        'gii'=>array(
            'generatorPaths'=>array(
                'bootstrap.gii',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'components'=>array(
        'bootstrap'=>array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bootstrap theme installing is not right. The right way is describe in [yii-bootstrap setup](http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/setup.html). So as You see there, you have to define its address at the first of your config/main.php file as below:

```
// Define a path alias for the Bootstrap extension as it's used internally.
// In this example we assume that you unzipped the extension under protected/extensions.
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap');
return array(
'theme'=>'bootstrap', // requires you to copy the theme under your themes directory
'modules'=>array(
    'gii'=>array(
        'generatorPaths'=>array(
            'bootstrap.gii',
        ),
    ),
),
'components'=>array(
    'bootstrap'=>array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
    ),
),
);
```